# Deeplinking to connect to Mobile Wallets using Wallet Connect

Tags: ethereum, metamask, wallet-connect

I am trying to create a mobile application that can connect to mobile wallets (Metamask and TrustWallet) via the WalletConnect Protocol. For reference, what I am trying to achieve would be something like what opensea and rarible mobile apps are doing - if you click on the connect to metamask button the app will take you to the metamask app (via deeplink) and you can approve the connection from the wallet.

I can generate a uri using wallet connect that will work if you scan it via QR Code but when I try to use it as deeplink, it will take me to the metamask application but not open the "would you like to connect" pop up. Here's an example of the deeplink im using:

metamask://wc?uri=wc:87dc2f44-42ff-4206-81bf-f2685730759d@1?bridge=https%3A%2F%2Fp.bridge.walletconnect.org&key=bbd16a77194580dc2c4b8caf02fd5d269bf9c0efdb7fbf91673bc3a7eadf0c25.

Just wondering if anyone has accomplished this and can share some insights

Comment: Hi, I have same problem, did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Hi finally I solved using below link:

The bidge must be https://bridge.walletconnect.org

```
Session.Config(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", key)
```

[from wallet connect sample](https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib/blob/master/sample/app/src/main/java/io/walletconnect/example/ExampleApplication.kt#L52)

Comment: Hey, can you please share the piece of code you use to have the wanted result. I have the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ok ill try that thank you !

Comment: I just update the answer

Comment: But did you clone the project ? Because when i do, it doesn't find any module..

Comment: I download zip file

Comment: Ok thx ill try this way

Comment: Do you also have a solution for iOS? Replacing the bridgeUrl with "https://bridge.walletconnect.org" still does not show the sign message.

Comment: I have this same issue but for nodejs